# GitHub - browse plain text version of markdown file

Tags: github, markdown

Please note this question is about simply **browsing** Markdown source code on the GitHub website, **not** how to add preformatted text when writing Markdown (or similar.)

---

GitHub automatically renders an HTML preview of Markdown files when you browse them in a repository. Here's one (purely random):

https://github.com/linode/docs/blob/master/docs/security/linux-security-basics.md

My question is, how do you switch to the standard GitHub plain text view you would for other code (e.g. a PHP file) – i.e. the source code of the .md file, with the clickable line numbers down the left, so you can refer to a specific line in a specific file in a specific commit in issues etc.

- I don't mean 'Raw', because there are no line numbers.
- I don't mean 'Edit' – which *is* better, but you still can't hover and highlight a line number / get a unique URL.

Answer (score 1):

On the MD file page, click on the RAW button.  it will take you to a different URL (in this case https://raw.githubusercontent.com/linode/docs/master/docs/security/linux-security-basics.md) but it shows the raw contents of the file, unformatted

Comment: Thanks, but I was after the 'pretty' view of the source (with clickable line numbers).  Have found & linked a duplicate question, which suggests it's not possible.

Comment: If you click to fork and edit, then you get the raw output with line numbers.  From there you can click on a line number which will show what the line relates to, if that helps